# Data Exploration Led Conversion to Ordinal Variable

Tags: data-cleaning, correlation

[I encountered this question at an interview few weeks ago and I am still not clear.]

If all the values in a categorical column `fuel_mileage` come from the set `{poor, good, very_good}`, then we can make the column ordinal due to universal and *ordered* relationship amongst `{poor, good, very_good}`, so this is kind of obvious.

However, imagine the label column in this same dataset is `engine_longevity`, so that we are studying all other variables in the context of their relationship with it. During data exploration, it turns out that another categorical column, `manufacturer`, all of whose values come from set `{H, S, J, K}`, has a very strong correlation with label `engine_longevity`, so much so that the choice of `H`, `S`, `J`, `K` in a given sample essentially dictates the label. Therefore, *as for as this data set is concerned*, `H`, `S`, `J`, `K` have an ordered relationship with respect to label `engine_longevity`. The question is:

1. Will you make column `manufacturer` ordinal? If yes, how strong should the relationship between `manufacturer` and the label `engine_longevity` be? And what metric will you use to measure it?
2. If you will not make `manufacturer` column ordinal, why?
3. More generally, should the choice of making a column ordinal come from the mutual-relationship of values within that column alone? Or, the relationship of values in a column with the label should be taken into consideration?

If there is no hard-and-fast rule, I would like to know how the community here will approach this situation.

Answer (score -1):

You are describing highly correlation features. The most common way to measure the correlation between two variables measured on at least an ordinal scale is the [Spearman rank-order correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient).

Generally if two features are near perfectly correlated, one feature can be dropped from analysis.